# Java ME: How to wipe all information from a device

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I am working in Java ME. I am trying to programmatically erase all user information, like messages and contacts, from my device.  I'm unsure which APIs I can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Contact list you can manage using [JSR-75 (PIM)](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/pim/index.html).  You could erase contacts using this API but it will probably require the user's permission for each individual contact.

There's no way to access the native Messaging inbox.